# change appdata folder location for single program in windows command shell

Tags: cmd

I am trying to run programs like chrome,firefox,minecraft and other programs off my usb and store application data for it on my usb in the folder data. it dosent seem to be working. instead, it is putting the appdata in default location.

Here is my code so far:

```
e:
cd \
cd programs
set appdata=e:\programs\data
cd bin
start firefox.exe
```

on my USB, I have this directory structure:

```
USB
 + Programs
    +-- Data
    +-- Programs
```

in my programs folder, i have:

- `firefox.exe`
- `chrome.exe`
- `minecraft.exe`

Comment: The location of `appdata` is typically obtained through a Windows API function, not from an environment variable. You would need to change the registry, which would be a permanent change affecting all programs, and you might not even have the rights to change the necessary registry setting.

Comment: I think firefox and chrome have an option to save bookmarks and other onto the usb.

Comment: i have admin priveleges.

Comment: @MarkRansom on the site http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/814010-100how-to-play-minecraft-off-your-usb-drive-any-computer-any-minecraft-version/ it shows that you can do it with environment varibles

Comment: So Minecraft uses the environment variable instead of the API. I can assure you that a lot of other software does it the other way around.

Comment: @MarkRansom then how do you change the appdata in the regestry temporaily using cmd?

Comment: You don't. Changing the registry haphazardly can put you into a lot of trouble. And it's *never* temporary.

Comment: What is the API?

Answer (score 0):

`set appdata=e:\programs\data` needs to be within double quotes, like so:

`set "appdata=e:\programs\data"`